# Refer to table column name that includes newlines and trailing spaces

Tags: excel, vba

This is a followup question of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941828/how-do-i-reference-an-excel-listobject-table-column-if-the-column-name-has-line). My question is that I have a table with a column named:

```
last˽˽˽˽˽˽˽˽˽˽˽
change˽˽˽˽˽˽˽
(weeks)˽˽˽
```

Where ˽ is a common space and there are two line breaks. (Don't hurt me, it wasn't me who created this column name.)

I am trying to do things with this column, e.g.

```
Sub test()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("myTable[last           " & vbLf & "change       " & vbLf & "(weeks)   ]").Hidden = True
    End With
End Sub
```

which fails for some reason. Having read the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941828/how-do-i-reference-an-excel-listobject-table-column-if-the-column-name-has-line), somebody commented to try `Debug.Print ActiveCell.Value` to see what the actual cell content is, but I have no idea where to put this code and where I would see the output. When I make a small Sub out of it and run it on the active cell, nothing happens:

```
Sub cellvalue()
    Debug.Print ActiveCell.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: You inserted only one vbLf, the second after change, before weeks is missing.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected it, but now it throws the error 1004

Comment: Regarding Debug.Print: You can write it e.g. after the line `Sub test()`, and you will see the output in the Immediate Window (in the VB Editor press Ctrl + G to get into this window).

Comment: Most probably, the reference is now correct, however, you cannot hide individual cells, only whole rows or columns, so you should insert .EntireRow or .EntireColumn before .Hidden.

Comment: Thanks. I did not nave teh immediate window enabled. But there I see just the pretty output with newlines and all. Taht did not tell me what to write into the Range(...)

Comment: Thanks! That was it. `.Range("Ticketliste[last           " & vbLf & "change       " & vbLf & "(weeks)   ]").EntireColumn.Hidden = True` works perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[z32a7ul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6306782/z32a7ul) has answered in his comment:

you cannot hide individual cells, only whole rows or columns, so you should insert .EntireRow or .EntireColumn before .Hidden.